# no output generated to make auto documentation by sphinx on fortran code

Tags: fortran, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, autodoc

We want to use autodoc tool Sphinx to make a documentation of fortran programs.
By using two extensions developed by vacumm ["vacumm.sphinxext.fortran_domain"](http://www.ifremer.fr/vacumm/user.desc.fdoc.dom.html#f/special_stats/rms) and ["vacumm.sphinxext.fortran_autodoc"](http://www.ifremer.fr/vacumm/user.desc.fdoc.auto.html), we are supposed to be able to parse fortran codes by Sphinx.

We can successfully run `make html` to generate html document files, but the output is empty. I mean, it seems that the fortran program has not been parsed and documented, but there is no error.

My program tree is like this:

```
├── doc
│   ├── _build
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _static
│   └── _templates
└── project
    └── caf10.f
```

conf.py includes:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../project/caf10.f"))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'vacumm.sphinxext.fortran_domain',
    'vacumm.sphinxext.fortran_autodoc'
]

fortran_src = [
    '/home/Documents/fortran-sphinx/project/caf10.f'
]
```

index.rst contains:

```
Documentation for the Code
**************************

.. f:autoprogram:: caf10

Contents:

.. toctree::
:maxdepth: 2 

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Fortran program is something like:

```
C Handling system components

      PROGRAM caf10
      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER NOERR, NSCOM, I
      CHARACTER FNAME*12, SCNAME*24

C Initialise program 
      CALL TQINI(NOERR)

      FNAME = 'cosi.dat'

C Open cosi.dat (system C-O-Si)
C for reading
      CALL TQOPNA(FNAME, 10, NOERR)

C Read data-file 
      CALL TQRFIL(NOERR)

C Close data-file 
      CALL TQCLOS(10, NOERR)


C Print the names of all system components
      WRITE(*,FMT='(A)') 'Names of system components:'

      DO I=1, NSCOM
         CALL TQGNSC(I, SCNAME, NOERR)
         WRITE(*,FMT='(I2,A)') I, ': ' // SCNAME
      ENDDO

      END
```

We don't have module or function definition in these fortran programs. We want to highlight the codes and comments, use cross references, and print the output of each method into the documentation.

The output of generated document is just the program name, and nothing else is included in the documentation:

```
program caf10
```

By running `make html`, it logs no error:

```
$ make html    

sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.2.3
loading pickled environment... not yet created
loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org/objects.inv...
parsing fortran sources... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
test1ng sources... [100%] index                                                                                                                        

/home/masood/Documents/fortran-sphinx-2/doc/index.rst:4: WARNING: test2
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                                                                         
writing additional files... genindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.
```

Do you have any idea how can we make a document which parsed the program, highlighted commands, included comments, and added cross references?

Comment: I know it's old, casual exploring of sphinx-contribs landed here.  Try setting `fortran_ext = ['*.f']` and `fortran_src = '/home/Documents/fortran-sphinx/project'`   fortran_src wants to be a list of glob patterns or a directory, I think.  Not tried, but it might make sense when mapping the `f:autoprogram:: caf10` directive.